# parsing versus serializing

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a file that is in the format:

```
1 4298 3598 39980 58903
39 3598 395 395 3598 3598
```

So just a bunch of numbers on each line (max number within 32bit signed int range).

My current code has to parse this every single time, first splitting the line into an array of strings and then converting each string to an int. Is there a faster way to do this via serialization or something that cuts out much of the parsing as I have to go over the same file many many times. I am happy to preprocess the file in other words.

Comment: I am not sure what you are after - parsing a file like this into a list of integer values are like what, 3 lines of code; I don't see how you want to "cut out much of the parsing" from that - please specify.

Comment: Errr.. that is a lot of CPU cycles that could be avoided if the code could just read in a binary format and assume it is a 32bit number. This file is very very large and I have to go over it thousands of times (nothing fits in memory).

Comment: I can't cache it, it is too large.

Comment: if you are reading line by line, your current logic sounds good to me. Only thing that you should take care is that if you need to refer the line again and again then cache it into memory instead of reading it again. Also, if you have to process n lines one after another - just keep your file handle open (so that you don't have to open and seek the relevant position in file again).

Comment: just read the comment - file being large - how large really? Anyway, you can implement caching where most recently used (or most used) lines can be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have the file in a binary format? The String conversions are completely unnecessary if you are only trying to get at the numerical values. Read in four bytes at the time and create an integer using them by means of bitwise operations. Serialization is a default mechanism designed to give the programmer an easy way to store objects, but a well-planned file format will work out to be easier and faster to parse.

Comment: This is what I am after, can you give me some ideas of c# code that might point me in the right direction? I can do it in c, but I am working with c# and can't do my unsafe magic tricks as far as I am aware.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know C#, but upon searching, I found that Microsoft provides the BinaryReader and BinaryWriter classes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.71).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.71).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is static and not massively large you might want to consider converting it to source code and compiling it into your program/system.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is all about taking a memory image of an object and transmitting or reading bytes into/out of that.  So unless you can force a `List<int>` to have that format, Serialization will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind giving up human-readability, you could encode each int as char in the file.  You can use Convert.ToChar(Int32) and Convert.ToInt32(char) for the conversion.  You'd want to test the performance and ensure that you don't run into issues if the char representation of the int isn't a valid character.